# Linux, use the keyboard with the screen turned off

Tags: linux, keyboard

I would like to know if there's any way to turn the screen off but keep the keyboard enabled (I would like to write with the keyboard without having to stare at the screen)

As for now I've been trying with

`sleep 1; xset dpms force off`

and

`sudo vbetool dpms off`

in the first case when I use the keyboard the screen turns back on. In the second case after turning it back on, with `sudo vbetool dpms on` for instance, the laptop freezes (can't use the keyboard or the mouse)

Any help is appreciated. keep in mind that I don't want to disable the keyboard, just not allow it to trigger the screen to turn on again. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about turning the brightness of your screen down to 0 and doing your typing?

Just make sure you have a terminal open that you can access somehow without being able to see the screen. You can do something like this using the `xrandr` command.

`xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --brightness 0.0`

Where your output device (your screen) is `eDP-1-1` (this is what it's called on my laptop, and you can get it's actual name using tab-completion following the `--output` argument of the command).

Comment: Do be careful not to lose access to that terminal.